# Losing the indexed data on updating in Solr

Tags: java, spring, solr

```
This is in schema.xml

<field name="body" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

This is the Java code

SolrInputDocument sdoc = new SolrInputDocument();
sdoc.addField("id",id);
Map<String, Object> fieldModifier = new HashMap<>();
fieldModifier.put("set", tags);
sdoc.addField("tags",fieldModifier);
solrClient().add(collectionName,sdoc);
solrClient().close();
```

I am trying to update the document in solr .The document gets updated but the indexed data of body field is lost after update (I can search using any other field than body).
How can I update and not lose the indexed data?

Answer (score 0):

As per the doc on [Atomic Updates](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html):

> The core functionality of atomically updating a document requires that all fields in your schema must be configured as stored (stored="true") or docValues (docValues="true") except for fields which are  destinations, which must be configured as stored="false".

Are you sure your body field has stored or docValues to true? The reason for that is that internally Solr is reindexing the whole doc, so those fields for which it has no way to recover the original data, are lost.